# Selenium 3 upgrade issue with class name

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have upgraded my selenium framework to selenium 3.4 version and I am getting the below errors:

If the Class Name has a space then `FindElement` fails to return list of `ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>`

What steps will reproduce the problem?

1.Not working:

```
FindElements(By.ClassName("CLASS NAME"));
```

2. Working:

```
FindElements(By.ClassName("CLASSNAME"));
```

Now most of xpath contains class name with spaces and my scripts`are not working.

To make all xpaths in my script without spaces is a huge task. It will take more time to maintain this.

Can anyone suggest me or do you have any work-around to make a minimal change and script will be fine?

Also will the selenium team fix this issue?

Comment: The same script worked before the upgrade? or did you change something else as well?

Comment: Can you add an example that includes the html and the exact code you are using?

Comment: @PrashantManakar Can you consider showing us some of your work please? Thanks

Comment: it's worth saying that trying to match on `CLASS NAME` is trying to match two separate css classes. I'd be surprised if using `By.ClassName` would work in that scenario (unless there was a bug). You are better off using `By.CssSelector`

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that there is no spaces allowed in a classname

If you are seeing classname like :

```
<input class="class name"/>
```

then it represents 2 classes first is `class` and second is `name`

Now come to selenium :

`By.className()` selector doesn't allows you to use compound classes. like `By.className("class name")`

If you want to manipulate compound class the you have to use xpath in this way

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='class name']")
```

OR CSS Selector in this way

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".class.name")
```